# Migration 2_deploycontract invalid or does not take any parameters

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, truffle-deployment

I am trying to create this token and for some reason, the second migration keeps giving me this

```
Migration 2_deploycontracts.js invalid or does not take in any parameters
```

1_initial_migrations.js seems to be working, I just don't know why the second one isn't.

So this is what I have got:
Migrations.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.12;

contract Migrations {
  address public owner = msg.sender;
  uint public last_completed_migration;

  modifier restricted() {
    require(
      msg.sender == owner,
      "This function is restricted to the contract's owner"
    );
    _;
  }

  function setCompleted(uint completed) public restricted {
    last_completed_migration = completed;
  }
}
```

Rxctoken.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.12;
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

contract Rxctoken {

    uint256 public totalSupply;

    constructor () public {
        totalSupply = 1000000;
    }
}
```

1_initial_migration.js

```
const Migrations = artifacts.require("./Migrations.sol");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};
```

2_deploycontract.js

```
const Rxctoken = artifacts.require("./Rxctoken.sol");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(Rxctoken);
};
```

Truffle version v5.1.66
I need help.

Comment: Try renaming or deleting build/ directory and recompiling again.

Comment: I tried that. It didn't work. I also have another issue where VSCode seems to be using a different compiler from truffle. but it still manages to compile and migrate other files, not just this one

Comment: I deployed the contracts and migrations scripts in ganache and they work without issues in node v10 and v14, truffle v5.1.67. I don't see another possible problem but there's something wrong in your environment.

Comment: wow thanks. I updated the truffle-config.js, update the solc version to the one i was using in vscode (0.7.4) and i did an ```npm install``` to install the dependencies and it worked seamlessly. thanks again

Comment: @Ismael i really need your help. I find it very difficult to get a good setup for Ethereum programming. Everything I do seems to break. I want to do a hard reset and a fresh install for everything. I wish you would guide me. I just want to use truffle and openzeppelin without any problems.

Comment: If you are just starting probably you want to check [Hardhat](https://hardhat.org/getting-started/). It is an alternative to truffle that is becoming very popular. They have a template that you can use to start working on https://github.com/nomiclabs/hardhat-hackathon-boilerplate. If you are using linux/mac try to install [`nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) so you don't have to deal with sudo and that kind of things. If you insist with truffle download an example from their [boxes](https://www.trufflesuite.com/boxes), like https://www.trufflesuite.com/boxes/pet-shop.

Comment: i have not had a stable environment with truffle. there is always something I have not done or something i am not doing right but i noticed a lot of people use it. i will give hardhat a try. but i don't even know if truffle is the problem. is it possible i installed something else wrong. I am on windows

Comment: Windows is not a first class citizen in blockchain world. It has a linux emulation layer created by microsoft you may want to try called WSL. As alternative use a virtualmachine so you won't break things. There's an alternative node manager [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) that mostly works. If you want to learn an easy alternative is use https://remix.ethereum.org it has most things and works from the browser without installing anything. For learning and quick test is excellent.

Comment: I am going to get linux and start my journey from there. I hope i will be able to reach you if i have any problems. Thank you very much.

Comment: i wanted to ask something. i'll probably just post it as a question. its too long